# What is the difference between let mapleader =”,”, and let g:mapleader=”,”

Tags: variables, leader, amix

In one of the most popular vimrc’s available (Aimx’s vimrc), there is a line which maps both leader and g:leader to “,”. https://github.com/amix/vimrc/blob/master/vimrcs/basic.vim#L58

1. What is the difference between let mapleader and let g:mapleader?
2. Why do you need both to be defined to “,”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `.vimrc`, there is no difference between them.

Without an explicit scope, vim chooses between `g:` and `l:` depending on the context. `l:` is implicit within functions, `g:` is implicit everywhere else.